# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

Tags: python, video, download, youtube, pytube

I am trying to download a YouTube video using [pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/). Here is my code:

```py
import pytube
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTVd_WxblGI"
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
stream = yt.streams.first()
stream.download()
```

But I am getting this error.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    stream = yt.streams.first()
  File "/home/harsha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
  File "/home/harsha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 181, in fmt_streams
    extract.apply_signature(stream_manifest, self.vid_info, self.js)
  File "/home/harsha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/extract.py", line 409, in apply_signature
    cipher = Cipher(js=js)
  File "/home/harsha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.throttling_plan = get_throttling_plan(js)
  File "/home/harsha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 387, in get_throttling_plan
    raw_code = get_throttling_function_code(js)
  File "/home/harsha/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py", line 301, in get_throttling_function_code
    code_lines_list = find_object_from_startpoint(js, match.span()[1]).split('\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

I installed pytube using `pip`. Please help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1243

Comment: Oh, thank you. This [comment](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1243#issuecomment-1032242549) solved my issue.